# Is it possible to eliminate redraw flicker in a badly written child control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, flicker, wndproc

**Short version**:
I'm using a WinForms control which flickers when being redrawn often. None of the existing "Double-buffer enable"-type solutions I found are effective, since this control literally does two distinct paint operations directly to it's drawing surface when redrawing. This control needs to be interactive (hence topmost on the form). Given that I *can* execute instructions right before this control starts repainting and right after it finishes repainting, is there anything the parent container or the containing Form can do to eliminate this control's flicker?

**Full explanation**:
I'm making a user control. A ListView as one of the children on it. I'm using the ListView to have columns on my control and all the functionality that a ListView's columns provide (hence, only the column header part of the ListView is actually visible on my control). I need to draw some additional information (let's call it "the overlay") where the ListView's column header are, but don't want to alter the 'look' of the column header otherwise. I obviously can't just draw the overlay from my user control in any way (the ListView is a child on my control and cover's up my control's drawing surface). I can't have a control on top of the ListView to function as the overlay's drawing surface - sure I can paint the ListView just fine on it and even preserve interactivity by messing with `WM_NCHITTEST` messages, but now the ListView does not get repainted, and I'm stuck with either redrawing the entire ListView on *any* mouse events or manually keeping track of which regions of the ListView need to be redrawn based on the events my overlay control receives (way too troublesome).

So the obvious solution is to override the ListView's column header's `WndProc` (like ObjectListView does it) and add my overlay drawing code there. So I have:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  switch (m.Msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
      RECT r = new RECT();
      WinAPI.GetUpdateRect(Handle, ref r, false);       //user32.dll - bool GetUpdateRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect, bool erase)
      Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right - r.Left, r.Bottom - r.Top);
         /* marker 1 */
      base.WndProc(ref m);                      //draw the column headers
         /* marker 2 */
      MyPaint(rc, Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle));   //draw overlay  (I'm aware of graphics needing to be disposed)
         /* marker 3 */
      return;
    }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Looks great! But when redrawing often, sometimes I will see on the screen the result of drawing only up to `marker 2`. It makes sense, of course, since I now have two distinct draw operations right onto the ListView's column header's drawing surface. Still, I can set whatever state I want in `marker 1` and `marker 3` so there must be some way for me to be able to suspend some drawing somewhere somehow right? Well, I can't for the life of me think of a way to do that. **So there's my question - is it possible?**

Basically, whatever solutions I tried to somehow suspend redraw, obviously trigger a redraw on 'un-suspend' resulting in endless `WM_PAINT`s. I was really trying to avoid just getting rid of `base.WndProc(ref m)` and drawing the column headers myself, along with whatever style drawing stuff that has to come along with it to preserve the column headers' native 'look'. But after fiddling with `WndProc`s for a few days, I'm starting to think that drawing the column headers from scratch is actually the least painful solution...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawcolumnheader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using DrawColumnHeader events / OwnerDraw makes the ListView not paint the column header at all, so I would still need to draw the column header from scratch. It's only syntactically better than what I'm doing, unless I'm missing something. I'm only trying to add more information to the column header and really want to avoid drawing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just realized that all this time I missed one rather simple solution - just have the base ListView draw to a different surface! So now I have:

```
case WM_Paint:
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  WinAPI.BeginPaint(Handle, out ps);            //user32 native calls
  Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(ps.rcPaint.Left, ps.rcPaint.Top, ps.rcPaint.Right - ps.rcPaint.Left, ps.rcPaint.Bottom - ps.rcPaint.Top);
  listview.DrawToBitmap(bmp, listview.ClientRectangle); //send yourself a WM_PRINT, pretty much
  buf.Graphics.SetClip(rc);                     //now just draw everything to a BufferedGraphicsContext buffer
  buf.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0);    //draw base ListView column header
  MyPaint(rc, buf.Graphics);                    //draw overlay
  buf.Render(Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle));        //flush buffer
  WinAPI.EndPaint(Handle, ref ps);              //validate drawing rectangle
  return;
```

No more flicker! Best part is, this answers the original question in a generic sense, as this technique can be used to 'fix' any badly-drawing control (or add additional drawing code to one), so long as the control properly handles `WM_PRINT` messages.